# PowerShell DSC load assembly

Tags: .net, powershell, .net-assembly, dsc

I have written a class based DSC resource. In this resource I need an assembly(Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll). I have tried to load the assembly with the manifest file: like that: `RequiredAssemblies = @("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll")`

Now I have the problem that when I want to write my DSC Configuration definion, I can't load my dsc resource because of the erromessage: Unable to find type [Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.Login]

Picture of the errormessage:
[image]

How can I load an assembly into my dsc session?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are after, but can you take a look here: https://github.com/PowerShell/xSQLServer/blob/dev/xSQLServerHelper.psm1

Comment: can you post what you have so far?

Comment: @ArcSet what do you want to see? I have added the errormessage from the config file

Comment: Have you tried 
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll");
    Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo

Comment: @ArcSet where should I load the assembly? in the dsc resource psm1 file or in th configuration script which creates the mof file?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that assembly is in the same folder as your module, and then call it like this (no dll): `RequiredAssemblies = @("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo")`

If that doesn't work, you can use reflection and load it into your AppDomain when the module is imported.

```
$assembly = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll'
$result = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($assembly)
if($result -eq $null)
{
    throw New-Object System.Exception("Failed to Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo assembly")            
}
```

Comment: The "RequiredAssemblies" way doesen't work. When I manually load the assembly it works fine. But when I run the script in the ISE with F5 or click on the script and use run with powershell it still throw the same error